# How to Create a Facebook App that redirects to a fanpage's photo album

Tags: facebook, photo

I'm trying to have a redirecting facebook application set as one of my four custom tabs on my facebook fanpage. I want it to redirect to a set album that's inside my fanpage's Photos on facebook.

For example: The album is named: What's On Sale. 
And inside are images of the items that are currently on sale at the store location.

I've followed various tutorails on how to create an application on facebook, but have not had any success. Is there some very simple way of doing this?

I feel like there should be, considering I'm just linking within facebook, and not externally.

Thanks, 
Jason

Comment: Could you post the code that you have actually used to try?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you know how to add a little javascript to the head of the page...

First, get the full URL of the photo album you want to redirect to, then you can use the following...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    top.location.href = 'ALBUM_URL_IN_HERE';
</script>
```

This will cause the page to immediately redirect to that URL.
Just make sure you put it at the top of the head section of your page.

I'm guessing you may also be having problem with which page is being loaded from your server when you open the tab for the application? Bit hard to guess at the moment, I think you may need a little more info in the question! :-)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! 

It seems as though I had two issues. First: a typo in my code. (Which I easily corrected thanks to the little snippet of code you had above)

And the second has to deal with my server's lack of SSL certificates. Seems as though I'll have to take care of that prior to using my app. 

Thanks again!